# Save changes in list

Tags: list

I would like to record all list changes in SharePoint. All records have a primary key. When I change something, it should be added like new row (which include changes). When I again change something and save change, I should to have three rows. Etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a SharePoint Designer workflow for that. You can set the Workflow up to run on all changes. In the workflow logic have the action `Create List Item` and set all the columns you need to set to help you record what is being changed and by who.